# WPF: Wizard control within Tab Item?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF page with a tab control and various tab items. Within one of the tab items, I want to present a two-step process, almost like a wizard. What combination of controls would accomplish this? I know I could use something like stackpanels with changing visibility, but I assume there has to be a better way than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free [Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) sports a nice [Wizard](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard&referringTitle=Home) control. You could use that within your tab item....

Answer (score 0):

We used [Avalon Wizard](http://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/) for our application and it worked out very nicely.